# Bind Date to SQLiteStatement

Tags: android, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have a precompiled insertstatment that looks like this

```
this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (name, date) VALUES (?, ?)");
```

I know how to bind the name

```
this.insertStmt.bindString(1, "Test");
```

But how can I solve this with a Date object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLite` does not have a storage class for `Dates`. See the [SQLite DataTypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

What I would recommend is to store your `Date` as `long`, in an `integer` column from your Database and when you fetch data from your database you could easily create a `Date` object from your `Cursor` by using:

```
   myDate=new Date(cursor.getLong(DATE_COL_INDEX));
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `SQLite` is quite able to properly cast string values into its types, so you can simply use bindString() and properly format the date yourself.

The following works for me:

```
stmt.bindString(1, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(someDate));
```